# Node.JS mock entire website and host it locally

Tags: node.js, download, proxy

I'm looking for a way to download an entire website contents and store it locally in my server so I could serve it later to clients.
Something in the line of proxying just that I want the files to be served from my node server and not from the remote server. I've searched for modules that can help me achieve that but have failed to find one.
Does anybody knows about such module or perhaps how to do it in a native way?

Comment: What is the success rate required? Downloading the page most of the time won't be enough, due to cross origin restrictions u will encounter. There do exist approaches when the entire website and its resources are traversed to alter all internal URL to make them go through ur server, but it might and will fail as long as new approaches of maintaining code base are introduced (e.g. usage of requireJS).

Comment: If you want to find rock solid approach to display the page from your server u might want to take a look at the scrapy. It is an open-source project, which we slightly altered, but it so far proven to be solid enough in majority of cases. http://scrapy.org/

Comment: @YerkenTussupbekov I look for a node.js solution. I intend that the success rate would be as high as possible. I encountered solutions such as http://testcafe.devexpress.com/ that are able to download all pages I've tried so far even few with cross origin restrictions. Can you think of anything I could use then to achieve it using node ?

Comment: If you want to display and use remote website through your domain, proxying is required. If you just want to download the client side code, there are many existing solution, simplest would be to `wget`

Comment: @YerkenTussupbekov Yes I wish to proxy the website and modify the response from the remote server. At the same time I want to the website to be served from my node server and make it so the proxy success rates of fetching all resources will be the highest it can. Those are pretty much my requirement and I'm looking for something to help me achieve this. At first I used the request module to download the content of a website and then tried to fiddle with it's content and adding some js and css files to it with jsdom. Unfortunately, this proven not successful so far because of conflicts between

Comment: scripts I load and scripts that the website I serve requiring (name conflicts of files and in the worst case variable, selector conflicts in js or css files). I also encountered problem fetching some of the resources as to cross origin restrictions as well as to some problem when trying to proxy particular websites, e.g is google.com which ended up looking like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/OPwc5.png (probably an encoding problem but also a problem with fetching some of the files like images, etc..)